# BayesianMinimization not giving the optimal values

Tags: performance-tuning, machine-learning

I was following the examples given in the [BayesianMinimization documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BayesianMinimization.html) and I found that this function actually does not give me the minimal value (very close though). Can anyone help explain the reasons behind this issue?

The problem can be reproduced by the following codes (following the documentation):

```
sampletest =  RandomSample[ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", "FisherIris"}, "Data"]];
trainingsample = sampletest[[1 ;; 100]];
validationsample = sampletest[[101 ;;]];
```

And then define a loss function in terms of the two hyperparameters and parameter space for optimization:

```
lossSVMRBF[{c_, gamma_}] := Module[
 {class},
 class =  
 Classify[trainingsample, 
  Method -> {"SupportVectorMachine", "KernelType" -> 
              "RadialBasisFunction", "SoftMarginParameter" -> Exp[c], 
     "GammaScalingParameter" -> Exp[gamma]}];
  -ClassifierMeasurements[class, validationsample, "LogLikelihood"]
 ];
reg2 = Rectangle[{-3., -3.}, {3., 3.}];
```

Conduct the Bayesian minimization:

```
boSVM = BayesianMinimization[lossSVMRBF, reg2]
```

The minimum configuration and minimum value can then be obtained by

```
boSVM["MinimumConfiguration"]
```

and

```
boSVM["MinimumValue"]
```

On my computer, the minimum configuration and minimum value with exactly the same code are `{1.74,-2.2}` and `2.15`, respectively.

Similarly, I also plot the predictor function and the *minimal* point given by BayesianMinimization (the red point)

```
pSVM = boSVM["PredictorFunction"]
pt2 = {Append[boSVM["MinimumConfiguration"], boSVM["MinimumValue"]]};
Show[
 Plot3D[pSVM[{x, y}], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", PlotLegends -> "Support Vector Machine-RBF", Exclusions -> False, PlotRange -> All], 
 ListPointPlot3D[pt2, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]]
]
```

[image]

Visually there are points lower than the red point, so I used `FindMinimum[pSVM[{x, y}], {x, 1.5}, {y, -2.0}]` to search around the minimal point, and get a lower point when `c= 1.56839, gamma=-2.51149` and the value is `1.55825` (the purple point in the above figure).

Comment: In machine learning, people often resort to very cheap but also very weak methods for minimization. So I am not surprised at all...